# How do I bind a key to open or close a mode? (undo-tree)

Tags: key-bindings, evil, undo-tree-mode

I'm using evil (via spacemacs) and I want to bind `<f2>` to open and close the undo-tree (like vim-Gundo). I can successfully bind opening `undo-tree-visualize`, but I can't figure out how to quit. I tried the obvious:

```el
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<f2>") 'undo-tree-visualizer)
(define-key undo-tree-visualizer-mode-map (kbd "<f2>") 'undo-tree-visualizer-quit)
```

It correctly opens undo-tree but doesn't close it (I get a "no undo information" error). I also tried to hook on load:

```el
(defun my-undo-tree-hook ()
    (define-key undo-tree-visualizer-mode-map (kbd "<f2>") 'undo-tree-visualizer-quit))
(add-hook 'undo-tree-visualizer-mode-hook 'my-undo-tree-hook)
```

But that also doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To get the same key to do different things in different contexts, bind it to a function that checks if the undo tree is open. You can use `get-buffer`[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586753/79125)]  [[2](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/get-buffer)] to check for the undo-tree window and use the variable for the buffer name:

```el
(defun undo-tree-visualizer-toggle ()
  (interactive)
  (if (get-buffer undo-tree-visualizer-buffer-name)
      (undo-tree-visualizer-quit)
    (undo-tree-visualize)))
;; You're usually in normal mode.
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<f2>") 'undo-tree-visualizer-toggle)
;; Inside the undo-tree, you're in motion mode.
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "<f2>") 'undo-tree-visualizer-toggle)
```

You can find variables with `C-h v` (with helm I incrementally searched for "undo-tree buffer" to find it).